# Centering an absolutely positioned item

Tags: css

I have the following text:

```
<p>This is the text</p>

p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
}
```

I want it to be 300px from the top, but **centered** in the browser (no matter the width), how would I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Not using `position: absolute` would be one option. What do you need it  for?

Comment: Is it *the text* that must be centered, or *the element*? For example, does the `p` have a `background`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a many ways to center something horizontally. But every way is for different conditions.

Here, I've added a fiddle with three versions of centering: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/5WMNE/

1. Just centering of text: cheap, but not fair.
2. For modern browsers you can use `transform: translate(-50%,0)` to align blocks, 'cause the percents in transforms are calculated from the elements' dimensions, not from the parents' ones. But it won't work in IE, however it's possible to write expressions that would emulate it.
3. And if you'd add en extra wrapper, you can use `inline-block` to center in truly.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the width to 100%, you can use text-align:

```
p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="outer">
    <p>This is the text</p>
</div>

p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 400px; /* or whatever half the width is */
}
#outer {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: "No matter the width" kind of rules this out, doesn't it?